# DynamoDB Table Modeling. Soft delete solution

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb

Hello stackoverflow community.
I am trying to organize soft delete solution for dynamodb.

If you have though on the same problem and find out any solution, please share in comment.

It involves thinking about: 
List items (isDeleted: false or 0), and use limit of results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to create `RANGE` index, for example `Number` with any data (0/1).

In my case it is `"isActive = 1"` for not deleted items.

Then we do query or scan with that IndexName.

In order to make item soft deleted, we need to remove attribute `"isActive"`

[DynamoDB Scan and Query with Index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.Indexes.QueryAndScan.html)

[Official Best Practice: Take Advantage of Sparse Indexes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForLSI.html#GuidelinesForLSI.SparseIndexes) - there is described our case.

In order to remove attribute use this example:

```
const params = {
      TableName: this.TABLE,
      Key: {
        _id: id
      },
      UpdateExpression: 'REMOVE isActive',
      ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW'
    }
    return dynamodb.update(params).promise()
      .then((data) => {
        if (data) {
          return data.Attributes
        }
        return null
      })
```